# Angular 7 recommended way to manipulate DOM without access to the underlying source code

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a 3rd party library which I don't have control over modifying the source code, I would like to add/remove a css class to an element on the DOM that the library produces.

Since I don't have access to the source code I can't add the class the way Angular recommends. So therefore my question is what is the recommended way to make this happen.

For example given this on the DOM (made up to make easy to understand):

```html
    <custom-control>
        <div class='one'>
        </div>
    </custom-control>
```

I've accomplished what I needed with the following method:

First inject ElementRef in the constructor of my component:

```js
    private myElement: ElementRef
```

Then use querySelector to get the element and add the class I want:

```js
    const ele = this.myElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.one');
    ele.classList.add('two');
```

In this example this would produce:

```html
    <custom-control>
        <div class='one two'>
        </div>
    </custom-control>
```

Later on (based on some logic) I then need to remove the class I added:

```
    ele.classList.remove('two');
```

**NOTE**: I don't have access to the 3rd party code, how would I accomplish the above the way angular recommends?

Answer (score -1):

you can use ::ng-deep selector in your styles file.

```
::ng-deep <class-name> {
    <property>: <value>
}
```

example:

```
::ng-deep .one {
    color: blue;
}
```

more about ::ng-deep https://ngrefs.com/en/latest/styling/ng-deep-selector

Comment: I also need to be able to remove the css class I added, this method would not be able to work for that case.